# how to get the common rows according to the first column in awk

Tags: awk

I have two `','` separated files as follow:

file1:

```
A,inf
B,inf
C,0.135802
D,72.6111
E,42.1613
```

file2:

```
A,inf
B,inf
C,0.313559
D,189.5
E,38.6735
```

I want to compare 2 files ans get the common rows based on the 1st column. So, for the mentioned files the out put would look like this:

```
A,inf,inf
B,inf,inf
C,0.135802,0.313559
D,72.6111,189.5
E,42.1613,38.6735
```

I am trying to do that in `awk` and tried this:

```
awk ' NR == FNR {val[$1]=$2; next} $1 in val {print $1, val[$1], $2}' file1 file2
```

this code returns this results:

```
A,inf
B,inf
C,0.135802
D,72.6111
E,42.1613
```

which is not what I want. do you know how I can improve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1],$2}' file1 file2
A,inf,inf
B,inf,inf
C,0.135802,0.313559
D,72.6111,189.5
E,42.1613,38.6735
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="," }  # set separators
NR==FNR {            # first file
    a[$1]=$0         # hash to a, $1 as index
    next             # next record
}
$1 in a {            # second file, if $1 in a
    print a[$1],$2   # print indexed record from a with $2
}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `awk` code basically works, you are just missing to tell `awk` to use `,` as the field delimiter. You can do it by adding `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` to the beginning of the script.

But having that the files are sorted like in the examples in your question, you can simply use the `join` command:

```
join -t, file1 file2
```

This will join the files based on the first column. `-t,` tells join that columns are separated by commas.

If the files are not sorted, you can sort them on the fly like this:

```
join -t, <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```